# Python pandas returns empty correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, correlation

I am running Python 2.7.6, pandas 0.13.1. I am unable to compute a correlation matrix from a DataFrame, and I'm not sure why. Here is my example DataFrame (`foo`):

```
                       A             B            C
2011-10-12   0.006204908 -0.0009503677  0.003480105
2011-10-13    0.00234903 -0.0005122284 -0.001738786
2011-10-14    0.01045599   0.000346268  0.002378351
2011-10-17   0.003239088   0.001246239 -0.002651856
2011-10-18   0.001717674 -0.0001738079  0.002013923
2011-10-19  0.0001919342  6.399505e-05 -0.001311259
2011-10-20  0.0007430615   0.001186141  0.001919222
2011-10-21   -0.01075129    -0.0015123  0.000807017
2011-10-24   -0.00819597 -0.0005124197  0.003037654
2011-10-25   -0.01604287   0.001157013 -0.001227516
```

Now I'll try to compute the correlation:

```py
In [27]: foo.corr()
Out[27]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
[0 rows x 0 columns]
```

On the other hand, I can compute correlations of each column to each other column. For example:

```py
foo['A'].corr(foo['B'])
# 0.048578514633405255
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: What version are you using? `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=list('ABC'), index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=10)); df.corr()` does work for me.

Comment: Your example works for me as well.

Comment: looks like you have ``object`` dtype of data (see the floats are not lined up). do an ``astype(float)``, or better yet where did the data come from? pls post ``foo.dtypes``

Comment: Ahh... good catch Jeff! That is quite odd. I'm not sure how the data was transformed to an object type, but I will certainly have to dig in. Thanks a lot for the pointer.

Comment: Wow, Jeff thanks a lot. I had a similar problem because I had Decimal objects.

Comment: I feel like Pandas should return an error and not an empty dataframe. Strange.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned in the comments, the problem resulted from my columns having the `object` dtype. For future reference, even if the object looks numeric, check the dtype and make sure it is numeric (e.g. do `foo.astype(float)`) before computing the correlation matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Since pandas 1.5.0, `corr()` has a `numeric_only=` parameter. If the values in the dataframe can be safely converted into floats, i.e. if `df.astype(float)` doesn't raise errors, then setting `numeric_only=False` makes `corr()` work for object/string/Decimal data.

```py
df.corr(numeric_only=False)
```

Example:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['0.006204908', '0.00234903', '0.01045599', '0.001717674'],
    'B': [Decimal('-0.07'), Decimal('-0.04'), Decimal('0.08'), Decimal('-0.07')],
    'C': ['0.003480105', '-0.001738786', '0.002378351', '-0.002651856']})


# pandas < 1.5.0
df.corr()

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []


# pandas >= 1.5.0
df.corr(numeric_only=False)

          A         B         C
A  1.000000  0.816457  0.827324
B  0.816457  1.000000  0.369191
C  0.827324  0.369191  1.000000
```